# memory leak in @autoreleasepool block

Tags: ios, ios5, memory-leaks, autorelease

I use Xcode 4.4 and I develope app for iOS 5.1 with ARC. I have a thread (other than main) that invokes periodically method below.

```
- (void)updateLabels:(NSTimeInterval)timeSinceLastUpdate
{
        int lastTime = self.time;
        self.scoreScale -= ((self.scoreScale-1)/5);
        self.time -= timeSinceLastUpdate;
        if (self.time <= 0) {
            self.time = 0.0;
        }
        if (lastTime != (int) self.time) {
            self.timeChanged = YES;
        }
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d:%.2d",(int)(self.time/60),((int)self.time%60)]; //leak!!!
        if (self.scoreScale <=1) self.scoreScale = 1;

        GLKBaseEffect *scoreValueEffect = [self.sprites objectForKey:@"score_value"];
        if (self.scoreChanged) {
            scoreValueEffect = [[ILUtils sharedInstance] makeEffectWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.score] alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft fontName:@"WetLetters EFN" fontSize:20 withViewSize:self.view.bounds.size withRect:CGRectMake(935, 50, 100, 30)];
        }
        scoreValueEffect.transform.modelviewMatrix = [[ILUtils sharedInstance] setupSpriteModelviewMatrixWithViewRect:CGRectMake(955, 46-(30*self.scoreScale-30)/2, 100*self.scoreScale, 30*self.scoreScale)];
        [self.sprites setObject:scoreValueEffect forKey:@"score_value"];

        if (self.timeChanged) {
            GLKBaseEffect *timeValueEffect = [[ILUtils sharedInstance] makeEffectWithString:timeString alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft fontName:@"WetLetters EFN" fontSize:24 withViewSize:self.view.bounds.size withRect:CGRectMake(955, 75, 100, 30)];
            [self.sprites setObject:timeValueEffect forKey:@"time_value"];
        }
    }
}
```

When I use Instruments I can see that memory usage increases in time. When I comment out line creating string memory usage is stable. I also tried to create string with alloc & init methods, but it didn't helped. I've found similiar thread in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=@autoreleasepool%20not%20working but enabling/disabling NSZombieEnabled option makes no difference.

I can't figure out why all these strings are not deallocated though I use @autorelease block as said in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html.

Did I miss something?
Thanks.

//EDIT
Stuff invoked by `makeEffectWithString`:

```
- (GLKBaseEffect*)makeEffectWithString:(NSString*)string alignment:(UITextAlignment)alignment fontName:(NSString*)name fontSize:(CGFloat)size withViewSize:(CGSize)viewSize withRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    GLKBaseEffect *effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
    effect.texture2d0.enabled = YES;
    effect.texture2d0.name = [self textureWithString:string dimensions:rect.size alignment:alignment fontName:name fontSize:size].name;
    effect.transform.projectionMatrix = [self setupOrthoProjectionMatrixWithViewSize:viewSize];
    effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = [[ILUtils sharedInstance] setupSpriteModelviewMatrixWithViewRect:rect];
    effect.useConstantColor = YES;
    effect.constantColor = GLKVector4Make(0.7f,0.7f,0.7f,0.7f);

    return effect;
}

- (GLKTextureInfo*)textureWithString:(NSString*)string dimensions:(CGSize)dimensions alignment:(UITextAlignment)alignment fontName:(NSString*)name fontSize:(CGFloat)size
{
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:name size:size];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, dimensions.width, dimensions.height, 8, dimensions.width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaOnly);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0);

    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    [string drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, dimensions.width, dimensions.height) withFont:font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:alignment];
    UIGraphicsPopContext();

    NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft];
    GLKTextureInfo *texture = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context) options:options error:nil];

    CGContextRelease(context);

    return texture;

}
```

//EDIT

```
- (void)drawSpriteUsingEffect:(GLKBaseEffect*)effect
{

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 20, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 20, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));

    [effect prepareToDraw];
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}
```

Comment: You probably need to show the hole updateLabels method

Comment: @Ecarrion
I have added whole method code as you requested.

Comment: and what about the method `makeEffectWithString`? i think thats the only place where you are using `timeString`

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't retain (or sth) the string as you can see in edited part of question.
Moreover, if I comment out the last `if` block (so the `timeString` won't be used anywhere) and leave creation line, memory leak will still occur. So `makeEffectWithString` definitely has nothing to do with issue.

Comment: There's something you're not telling us.  (Where is the category for NSString drawInRect, eg?)

Comment: NSString drawInRect is declared in category `NSString(UIStringDrawing)` in `UIStringDrawing.h` which is part of `UIKit`.

Comment: What do you mean by "memory leak"? Did you use the Leaks instrument and it says it's a leak?

Comment: @newacct
I mean I used Allocations and Leaks instrument and here is the screenshot in the beginning of app run (look at `CFString` values) http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/381/screen1dj.png,
then after few minutes I had that http://img99.imageshack.us/img99/5691/screen2ar.png memory usage for `CFString` and total memory usage over 100MB http://img98.imageshack.us/img98/9118/screen3sxx.png.

Comment: @gmm: that's the Allocations tab selected. Actually go into the Leaks tab to see what's leaked

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Allocations instruments to "Mark Heap". [This](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) seems to have some instructions on how to debug such memory issues.

Comment: @newacct
@Dhaval
I'm refreshing issue after I had to postpone it for a few days. I've played around with Leaks and "Mark Heap", but I'm still unsure what causes a leak. Here are some results:
http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/580/heapshot.png
(In Heapshots I have turned on flattening recursion due to illegible call tree,   `+[GLKShaderBlockNode copyTreeWithRoot:parent:]` invoked many times)

http://img155.imageshack.us/img155/2075/leakst.png
In Leaks _all_ positions had `-[GLKShaderBlockNode copyWithZone:]` value in "Responsible Frame".

Comment: Cannot edit after 5 minutes, second link is invalid, here is the right one: http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/3997/leaks.png